# Why do I have to call to the '/answerCallbackQuery' endpoint to know if a user pressed an InlineButton in my Telegram bot?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot

I'm creating a Telegram bot using Python (using the requests package to make API calls) which sends a message with two inline buttons to a user; pressing a button sends a callback query back to the bot, which performs a different function based on which button has been pressed.

I've read on the API docs that the client will show up an animation until the bot calls the '/answerCallbackQuery' endpoint to receive the callback call from the button.

To do so I need to know the callback query's id, but the only way I know of obtaining it is by calling the '/getUpdates' endpoint to get all the updates, somehow find the correct field and then use the 'id' field as the `callback_query_id` parameter in the `answerCallbackQuery` call.

So to receive to get notified about a button being pressed I need to do 2 API calls, am I getting it right or is there a simpler method?
Since I'm already getting the info I need by the `getUpdates` endpoint, why should I bother making another call to the `answerCallbackQuery` one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> pressing a button sends a callback query back to the bot, which performs a different function based on which button has been pressed.

This is only valid if you have [Webhooks](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getting-updates) enabled. Otherwise you'll still have to call `getUpdates` to check if the user pressed a button.

---

> but the only way I know of obtaining it is by calling the '/getUpdates' endpoint to get all the updates

You've already called `getUpdates` since thats the only way of retrieving the actual button press update.

---

> I need to do 2 API calls, am I getting it right or is there a simpler method?

Yep, `getUpdate` to retrieve the press, `answerCallbackQuery` to let Telegram know you've progressed the press.

---

> why should I bother making another call to the answerCallbackQuery one

Well, Telegram can't assume you're processing those button presses, you'll need to tell Telegram that you've processed it. Just as the documentation states, mostly a simple notification on the top of the screen, or in most cases, removing the keyboard since the user has used it.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my problem, or I didn't explain it clearly. I know I need to call `getUpdates`, and I did so. My doubt consists in why should I do make another call to a different endoint, `answerCallbackQuery` just to let know the client I received I got notified about it. I mean, I can already see through the `getUpdate` response that the button got pressed, and all the data regarding it. Through that call I retrieve all the "notification" like the button being pressed. To me it looks a lot of unnecessary code so I was hoping to get also some explanation.

Comment: But thats the 4'th point right? Receiving the update does not equal 'processed' the update. So Telegram cant assume you've processed it after you've called getUpdates. You'll need to call answerCallbackQuery for that. Hope I'm clear enough.